# Increase Chrome Remember Password Pop-Up Duration

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any settings in chrome ( including development mode being turned on ) from where I can simply increase the remember password pop-up duration ?

Comment: Wait, you mean the duration for the dialog itself to press "remember" right?

Comment: @LPChip (was abt to comment this on ur ansr) I guess you misinterpreted my question: what I wanted is to increase the duration of pop-up (that comes at the top-right corner)